Multi-project template Visual Studio 2022 - simplify exporting
Framework/Versions

VS 17.8
.NET 8

Problem
I'm struggling to streamline the exporting process for my custom multi-project template.
Solution layout:

The only way I've managed to produce a working multi-project template is by performing the following:

Find/Replace all instances of my current project name with $ext_safeprojectname$.
Export each project as a Template individually.
For each resulting template zip, unzip it into the final template folder.
Add a MyTemplate.vstemplate file to the root of this folder.
Zip it up and place in VS 2022 templates directory.

Here is the resulting folder structure:

Here are the contents of the .vstemplate file:
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>My Wasm Template</Name>
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Client" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Client\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Server" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Server\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Data" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Data\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Shared" CopyParameters="true">
                MyWasmTemplate.Shared\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>

Question
Is there a better way to do this? I made an attempt at writing a Powershell script for it, but I can't seem to programatically replicate the behaviour of the Export Template wizard in VS.
My method produces a reliable template, but it takes far too long.
